# Firebase Cloud Function with Swagger: Error: could not handle the request

Tags: google-cloud-functions, swagger-ui

I have this code in a function called `docs`:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const express = require("express");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");

const swaggerJsdoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");

const options = {
  definition: {
    openapi: "3.0.0",
    info: {
      title: "API",
      version: "1.0.0",
    },
  },
  apis: ["../**/*.function.js"], 
};

const openapiSpecification = swaggerJsdoc(options);
console.log(" ", openapiSpecification);

const app = express();

app.use(
  "/",
  swaggerUi.serve,
  swaggerUi.setup(openapiSpecification, {
    swaggerOptions: {
      supportedSubmitMethods: [], //to disable the "Try it out" button
    },
  })
);

module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

But every time I hit the URL, this error gets returned:

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

URL:

```
https://REGION-PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/docs
```

The deps above are all installed.

Any idea what is causing this issue?
Or better yet, how can I serve an endpoint for Swagger docs?

Please keep in mind that all other functions don't use express; most are callable. Just this one function uses it, so not sure if the mixing not supported.

Here's the folder structure:

```
package.json
index.js
app
    auth
        login.function.js
    users
        createUser.function.js
```

Inside `index.js`, the functions get loaded and added to the `exports` dynamically. This setup works fine and deploys well, so no issues there.

Comment: Can you also show your folder structure as we don't know what lies in the `../**/*.function.js` and If possible provide reproducible steps. I have found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74803435/setting-up-swagger-ui-in-firebase-functions-server) and this [article](https://dev.to/kabartolo/how-to-document-an-express-api-with-swagger-ui-and-jsdoc-50do) which could help you.

Comment: @RohitKharche I updated the question with folder structure info. I already seen your links, neither helped.